# Não permitir inserir símbolo € num input

Tags: html

Estou a fazer um site de inserção de dados na base de dados e não quero que seja possível inserir o símbolo do euro "€" no input.
Existe alguma forma de bloquear isso?

Comment: `<input type='number' step='0.01'>` já ajuda, mas convém fazer verificação no lado servidor depois

Answer (score 1):

Sim, você pode fazer inicialmente uma verificação usando Javascript, e para segurança outra verificação na linguagem imperativa na qual você esteja criando seu site, tipo PHP, Ruby, Python, antes de gravar no banco de dados.

Para verificar em Javascript, basta modificar o tipo do botão de enviar, de "submit" para "button" e adicionar um evento ao clicar para executar uma função em JavaScript na qual verificara a presença do símbolo "€" antes de enviar.

No PHP antes de gravar no banco de dados é altamente aconselhável fazer a verificação novamente.

Comment: e poderá ajudar-me com código? É que não sei como irei fazer...

Answer (score 0):

Coloca isto no teu codigo, Este codigo elimina o simbolo €, por exemplo:

1,43€ fica 1,43

Mas certifique-se que ao fazer o insert na BD usa a variavel result.

```html
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "a sua variavel aqui";
    var patt1 = /[^€]/gi; 
    var result = str.match(patt1);
}
</script>
```

Comment: nao esta a funcionar

Answer (score 0):

isto resolve e impede ainda de escrever letras

```
function allowOnlyNumbers(e) {
var tecla = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.which;
if ((tecla > 47 && tecla < 58)) return true;
else {
    if (tecla == 8 || tecla == 0) return true;
    else return false;
}};
```

`i<input id="input" type="number" onkeypress="return allowOnlyNumbers(event)"/>`